# wcf - customizing service document

Tags: wcf, service, document, atompub

I am new to WCF programming and its syndication classes etc. I am trying to produce a AtomPub service document programmatically when someone tries to access root address of my service. I am able to do that only to some extent using ServiceDocument, ResourceCollectionInfo, Workspace classes -

```
<service>
<app:workspace>
    <a10:title type="text">Sample Repository</a10:title>
    <app:collection href="http://some_url">
        <a10:title type="text">Root Collection</a10:title>
    </app:collection>       
</app:workspace>
</service>
```

However I would like to add some **custom** attributes and elements as can be seen below. Please notice the xmlns attributes, cmisra elements etc.

```
<service 
xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" 
xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/">
<workspace>
    <atom:title>Sample Repository</atom:title>      
    <collection href="http://some_url"> 
      <atom:title>Root Collection</atom:title> 
      <cmisra:collectionType>root</cmisra:collectionType>
    </collection> 
</workspace>
</service>
```

There is nothing much available on msdn website or elsewhere. Any inputs on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ResourceCollectionInfo` class has two properties `ElementExtensions` and `AttributeExtensions` which can be used to customize the serialization of a `ResourceCollectionInfo`. Please note that most of the syndication elements have those extensions, which work with both the RSS and Atom formatters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did reach to this answer a few days back while checking on the web. But this was exactly the answer I was hoping for.